# jQuery UI Datepicker is not installing

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I am trying to install datepicker on my webpage. But it doesn't appear in browser. I have several script files, is there any problem with other files ?

Here is my datepicker div

```
<body>
<!-- Preloader -->
<div id="preloader">
    <div id="status">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
<!--====== NAVIGATION MENU ==========-->
<?php include 'header.php'; ?>
<section>
    <div id="datepicker"> Here Datepicker</div>
    <div class="tb-space tour-consul">
    . . . . . . rest of codes
```

Here is js and css file link:

```
<link href="dist/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="dist/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>

<script>
$( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ minDate: -0, maxDate: "+1M +15D",  });
});
</script>
```

But with same js and css files, only datepicker div works on a single page.

Comment: Put your script at the bottom of your page before the closing </body>, or make sure to execute any jquery function when the DOM is already loaded.

Comment: I have tried this, but same result.

Comment: use text input not div

Comment: can you upload a working code in jsfiddle

Comment: @KapilaPerera http://pastebin.com/MV8mthaf This is my file works on my local server.
And this is jsfiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/aosa3joj/ it's doesn't work too.

Comment: after adding those references I manage to work your code 
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

Answer (score 0):

### Edit - Real problem - For future finder

The real problem seem to be the load order of the script.

jquery must come before jquery ui

hence this does not work (checkout the external resource order)

https://jsfiddle.net/aosa3joj/

```
<link href="dist/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="dist/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
```

but change the order works

https://jsfiddle.net/aosa3joj/1/

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<link href="dist/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="dist/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

---

### original answer

My first instinct is try change div to input type="text", it should be a input not div

Comment: I have tried this one too, but when I changes to input it shows only a text field, after click doesn't appear calendar.

Comment: check your developer console (F12) - do you see any error on the console?

Comment: it could be your jquery ui css and js path is not correct, try use full url path, or use cdn for testing: jquery ui - https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js and the css https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css

Comment: Yes, there is 2 error:
1. Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
2 .Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function

Comment: that seems like you jquery is not loading correctly, try put your jquery-1.12.4.js script **before** the jquery ui js and css, make it the first to load

Comment: Actually it conflicts with other js file may be, what I thought. Now only 1 error,
 Here is full error message: 
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (home.php:382)
    at j (jquery-latest.min.js:2)
    at k (jquery-latest.min.js:2)
(anonymous) @ home.php:382
j @ jquery-latest.min.js:2
k @ jquery-latest.min.js:2

Comment: check this out - it is your loading order as I suspected https://jsfiddle.net/aosa3joj/1/
see the external source jquery came before jquery ui

Comment: It works in jsfiddle, just because of there is no other files. As I mentioned in my question, there are other js files. after rearranging links as yours, still have this one error : Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (home.php:39)
    at fire (jquery-1.12.4.js:3232)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-1.12.4.js:3362)
    at Function.ready (jquery-1.12.4.js:3582)
    at HTMLDocument.completed (jquery-1.12.4.js:3617)

Comment: Then it seems like your jquery ui is not loading correctly, hence not finding the .datepicker function - checkout your network tab, and see if jquery-ui.js is loaded with status code 200

Comment: check out the html page generated - and check you are not loading jquery again after loaded jquery-ui.js

Answer (score 0):

Make sure , file jquery-ui.css in tab header

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have the right css and js references.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```